# Is there a framework or method for string encryption, which can be used in JavaScript, Swift and Kotlin?

Tags: javascript, swift, kotlin

I want to setup a system which can write and read encrypted/decrypted data from a server. The application is programmed in Swift, JavaScript and Kotlin. Is there a framework or method that can encrypt data in e. g. Swift and decrypt it after being downloaded from the server in e. g. Kotlin? It's import that the same encryption/decryption is used in all three programming languages.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. You’ll have to be more specific to get a good answer.

Comment: Just use any standard algorithm. I doubt you'd find a framework that runs the same in those three languages, but you will find distinct implementations that do the same encryption/decryption.

Comment: And questions looking for tools are off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you communicate between them all using HTTPS, everything is secure anyway..